# Facebook Login not happening through Parse.com Android?

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I have created Parse Application. Created a facebook application noted down ApplicationId, Hashkeys and updated Parse Application. Following are code snippets i have done to achieve FB integration.

First initialised Facebook application with Parse.com in Application class as follows:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(FB_APPLICATION_ID);
```

Have updated android manifest as follows:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
```

Following is code to login in Parse.com

@Override
                        public void done(final ParseUser user,
                                ParseException exception) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                if (user.isNew()) {
                                    System.out.println(ParseFacebookUtils
                                            .getSession().getAccessToken());
                                }

```
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                    HomeScreenActivity.class));
                            getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0).edit()
                                    .putString(TWITTER_LOGIN, LOGIN_PLATFORM)
                                    .commit();
                            getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0).edit()
                                    .putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGGED, true).commit();
                        } else {

                        }

                    }
                });
```

However when this code executes in shows loading and comes back to same screen rather than showing facebook dialog.

Saw logcat has following in it:

```
Displayed com.facebook.katana/.ProxyAuthDialog: +229ms (total +247ms)
Activity com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuthDialog has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$Connection@423302c8 that was originally bound here
```

02-08 19:45:25.412: E/ActivityThread(21197): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuthDialog has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.org.chromium.com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.selfbraille.SelfBrailleClient$Connection@423302c8 that was originally bound here
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved this. You need to override onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```